# Add a card to favourites tab using a button on the card, and using the same button I want to remove the card from the favourites tab

Tags: javascript, html, button, cart

Using a 'like button(class="heart")', I want to add a 'whole card(id="drag1")' to a 'Favourites Tab(class="dropzone")', which is also a section in my website. And from the click on the like button, I want to remove the card from it's original position(class="section_3") too. And also I want to do this in reverse using the same 'like button'(removing the card from the favourites tab and moving back it to it's original position).
{This card is also designed to do the drag & drop to the 'favourites tab' too. It's already applied}

```
html
```

```
  <div class="drop section_2">
    <div class="dropzone" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="title"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="section_3" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    <!-- card 1 -->
    <article class="card draggable" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <div class="card__wrapper">
    
        <figure class="card__feature">
          <img src="./img1.jpg" class="card__img" alt="Estates" width="275" height="240">
        </figure>
    
        <div class="card__box">
    
          <header class="card__item card__header">
            <h6 class="card__item card__item--small card__label">Featured</h6>
            <h2 class="card__item card__item--small card__title">Blue Ocean Waves Crash</h2>
          </header>
    
          <hr class="card__item card__divider">
    
          <section class="card__item card__body">
            <p>See the beautiful oceans of the Pacific coast where the water is so clean you can see the sand.</p>
          </section>
          
          <div class="card_btns">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="eye" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M2.036 12.322a1.012 1.012 0 010-.639C3.423 7.51 7.36 4.5 12 4.5c4.638 0 8.573 3.007 9.963 7.178.07.207.07.431 0 .639C20.577 16.49 16.64 19.5 12 19.5c-4.638 0-8.573-3.007-9.963-7.178z" />
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 12a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z" />
            </svg>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="heart" viewBox="0 0 24 24" onclick="addToCart(drag1)">
              <path stroke-linejoin="round" d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12z" />
            </svg>
          </div>

        </div>
    
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
```